# CORS with gevent

Tags: python, http, cors, gevent

I am building a gevent application in which I use `gevent.http.HTTPServer`. The application must support CORS, and properly handle HTTP OPTIONS requests. However, when OPTIONS arrives, HTTPServer automatically sends out a `501 Not Implemented`, without even dispatching anything to my connection greenlet.

What is the way to work around this? I would not want to introduce an extra framework/web server via WSGI just to be able to support HTTP OPTIONS.

Comment: cant find gevent.http.HTTPServer what version of gevent are you using ? did you try to use pywsgi.WSGIServer instead ?

Comment: I use gevent 0.13.7. pywsgi would probably work, however I do not want to use WSGI in this particular application.

Comment: whats wrong with that ?

Comment: Unnecessary overhead.

Comment: I dont want to spoil too much (its fun to do this things) but believe me, you are going to need so many extras than gevent.http.HTTPServer if you want to run this on production than 40 lines of python code are not going to matter that much :)

Answer (score 0):

Practically the only option in this situation is to switch to using WSGI. I ended up switching to pywsgi.WSGIServer, and the problem solved itself.

It's important to understand that switching to WSGI in reality introduces very little (if any) overhead, giving you so many benefits that the practical pros far outweigh the hypothetical cons.